# jquery, div with table is not visible when I call show();

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div id="abclink">
    + click here to view
</div>
<div id="abctable" style="display: none;">
    some text here, allot of text
</div>
```

So using jquery I try and do:

```
$("#abclink").bind("click", function() {

     $("#abctable").show();
});
```

This doesn't work, and I don't know why?

Comment: @galambalazs - They are two different elements. They just look like the same at first glance because they both start with `#abc`. :o)

Comment: right i missed that. sry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be missing the document.ready function. Also, it might be best to use toggle instead of show:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#abclink").bind("click", function() {
  $("#abctable").toggle();
 });
})
```

Answer (score 3):

you have to put a #

```
$("#abclink").bind("click", function() {

     $("#abctable").show();
});
```

Comment: putting an alert('hello') inside the click event doesnt' do anything either.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing #abclink doesn't exist at the point you're trying to bind the event. Are you doing it in the  of the page? If so, try putting it in the document.ready event:

```
$(function() {
    [your code]
});
```